# How to compress JPEG images with ASP on Windows CE

Tags: asp-classic, compression, windows-ce, jpeg

The ASP page gets data uses that to draw a graph, I then need to save the image created to JPEG to be displayed on the browser and also used in PDF and other format. What is the best way to compress the image? I am currently porting a JPEG compression library to ASP but I think it will be too slow on this ARM device running Windows CE 6.0.

So, the ASP page, running in Windows CE webservers, gets data, renders it into a bitmap image than then needs to be delivered to the browser accessing that ASP page. The same image is also used in PDF and one other proprietary format that can contain JPEG streams.

Edit:
What I am looking for is to way to create an array representing a bitmap and then compressing it to JPEG with ASP in Windows CE's IIS which has quite limited ASP implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Imaging APIs (start your traversal at the [IImagingFactory interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452202.aspx)).  If your device has a JPG compression codec installed (remember that CE is modular, so it may or may not be present) you can use it to create a stream (or file) from the image.  From there you can do with it what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused...

The images from ASP would be compressed on the server side--not client side.

I'm sure your web server is not running on Windows CE, so I don't think your concern is warranted.

**EDIT:** Seems as though you can run a web server on Windows CE: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/embedded/products/windowsce/default.mspx.  I'll keep my thoughts to myself from now on. :-x